# MySQL GROUP BY and INNER JOIN - groupping by the joined fields

Tags: mysql, group-by, inner-join

Considering the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(table1.someField), COUNT(table2.someField)
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id
GROUP BY table1.id
```

I am trying to understand what the difference is (if any) between groupping by `table1.id` and groupping by `table2.id`. In short, when inner joining two tables on `X=Y`, what the difference is when groupping by `X` and when groupping by `Y`. That's it.

---

**The real world example** - pretty straightforward: a table `transaction` holds transactions information (paid amount, dates etc), and a table `transaction_product` holds information regarding which products were included in which transaction.

So for example, transaction number 1 could have included products number 1, 2 and 3, and so forth (so the table relation is obviously one-to-many).

**The problem:** I need to know for each transaction, how much was paid for how many products. This is the query, including both GROUP BY alternatives:

```
SELECT 
    `transaction`.id,
    SUM(`transaction`.transaction_amount) AS total_amount, 
    COUNT(`transaction_product`.product_id) AS number_of_products
FROM `transaction`
INNER JOIN `transaction_product` ON `transaction_product`.transaction_id = `transaction`.id
GROUP BY [`transaction`.id [OR] `transaction_product`.transaction_id]
```

I need to know if there is a difference between the two GROUP BY alternatives. I couldn't find relevant information regarding the GROUP BY behavior in this case in the documentation, therefore any help on clarifying the matter would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The result of the `inner join` will be a set of rows with matching transaction IDs, so the set of values that column can have will be the same on both `transaction` and `transaction_product` tables.
2. The `group by` will return a single row for each available value of the grouped column(s), and all the rows that share the same value will be aggregated with the aggregation function you use. The result

Result: there won't be any difference between the two options you have, because the same rows will be grouped with the exact same criteria, being the set of values the same on both sides.

**TL/DR**

There is no difference at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference whatsovever which id you choose to include in your GROUP BY clause. The total number of rows for each transaction id will be the number of products for that transaction. This query should get what you need:

```
SELECT 
    `transaction`.id,
    SUM(`transaction`.transaction_amount) AS total_amount, 
    COUNT(1) AS number_of_products
FROM `transaction`
INNER JOIN `transaction_product` ON `transaction_product`.transaction_id = 
`transaction`.id
GROUP BY `transaction`.id
```